# efficient processing of large amounts of data from a web socket in R

Tags: r, websocket

I am using the "websocket" library to process quotes from the Binance exchange. My script processes a large amount of incoming data and finds abnormally large data in them, which it stores in a small file. I ran into a problem in the processing speed of a large data stream. This results in a significant processing delay. How can I handle such large streams efficiently? unfortunately I cannot reproduce an example here, but I would like to know about the general practices of processing large amounts of data

```
DataProcess <- function(message){
  data <- message   # I assign the incoming message to a variable
  ticker <- data$s  # I get from the message the name to which the data belongs
  bid <- data$b     # data in which I am looking for large values
  ask <- data$a     # data in which I am looking for large values
  orderBook <- c(bid, ask) # data in which I am looking for large values
  secondValuesNumeric <- as.numeric(sapply(orderBook,"[[",2)) # 
  maxIndex <- which.max(secondValuesNumeric) #
  biggest_size <- orderBook[[maxIndex]] # 3 lines with which I find the highest value in the received message
  x <- list(symbol = ticker, biggest_size) 
# I create a connection to the file in which the last recorded large value is stored
  con <- file(description = paste(ticker, '.txt', sep = '')) 
#if the largest value in the received data is greater than the specified large value and the price at which this value is located is not equal to the last recorded one, then I rewrite the incoming message to the file and send the message to the messenger
  if (as.double(x[[2]][2]) > dat$bigSize[dat$ticker == ticker] & !isTRUE(all.equal(as.double(readLines(con = con, n = 1, warn = F)), as.double(x[[2]][1])))) {
    writeLines(paste(x[[2]][1]), con)
    bot$send_message(chat_id = -498542337, 
                     text = paste(ticker, ': ', 'Large size for the price: ', x[[2]][1], ' Volume: ', x[[2]][2]))
  }
  close(con)
}


$e
[1] "depthUpdate"

$E
[1] 1616530913906

$T
[1] 1616530913402

$s
[1] "COMPUSDT"

$U
[1] 276620494586

$u
[1] 276620494586

$pu
[1] 276620491003

$b
$b[[1]]
[1] "379.81" "0.170" 

$b[[2]]
[1] "379.80" "2.200" 

$b[[3]]
[1] "379.79" "0.486" 

$b[[4]]
[1] "379.75" "4.269" 

$b[[5]]
[1] "379.74" "1.410" 

$b[[6]]
[1] "379.71" "0.427" 

$b[[7]]
[1] "379.68" "1.208" 

$b[[8]]
[1] "379.67" "3.949" 

$b[[9]]
[1] "379.66" "1.115" 

$b[[10]]
[1] "379.65" "7.200" 

$b[[11]]
[1] "379.58" "0.308" 

$b[[12]]
[1] "379.57" "0.500" 

$b[[13]]
[1] "379.55" "1.100" 

$b[[14]]
[1] "379.53" "1.000" 

$b[[15]]
[1] "379.45" "1.855" 

$b[[16]]
[1] "379.41" "5.333" 

$b[[17]]
[1] "379.36" "3.149" 

$b[[18]]
[1] "379.33" "6.838" 

$b[[19]]
[1] "379.32" "10.000"

$b[[20]]
[1] "379.31" "0.806" 


$a
$a[[1]]
[1] "380.09" "0.658" 

$a[[2]]
[1] "380.10" "0.345" 

$a[[3]]
[1] "380.12" "0.490" 

$a[[4]]
[1] "380.18" "1.000" 

$a[[5]]
[1] "380.20" "1.028" 

$a[[6]]
[1] "380.21" "2.476" 

$a[[7]]
[1] "380.22" "1.689" 

$a[[8]]
[1] "380.28" "0.846" 

$a[[9]]
[1] "380.30" "11.570"

$a[[10]]
[1] "380.34" "16.795"

$a[[11]]
[1] "380.35" "7.689" 

$a[[12]]
[1] "380.36" "2.984" 

$a[[13]]
[1] "380.37" "1.920" 

$a[[14]]
[1] "380.38" "5.508" 

$a[[15]]
[1] "380.39" "1.565" 

$a[[16]]
[1] "380.40" "14.881"

$a[[17]]
[1] "380.41" "19.781"

$a[[18]]
[1] "380.42" "3.557" 

$a[[19]]
[1] "380.43" "6.826" 

$a[[20]]
[1] "380.44" "13.258"
```

Comment: I think there are too many unknowns here for us to really help. When you say *"processing delay"*, is there an expectation of near-real-time processing? Who or what is consuming this processed data? What type of processing are you doing? Bottlenecks can be in too many places for a question this vague to be reasonably answered. (Heck, the only things I know for certain are that you are using R, the `websocket` package, and large amounts of data.)

Comment: I added a fix in which I stuck my function for handling messages with comments

Comment: Can you provide a small representative sample of `message` here? Something we can use on the console, likely from `dput(x)` where `x` is a heavily reduced version of your real data.

Comment: added an example of a message that is processed by the function